# writing json record from dataframe column to S3 in spark streaming

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-kafka, user-defined-functions, spark-structured-streaming

I have a drataframe shown in below format with records as json data (which is in string format) read from kafka topic

[image]

I need to write just the json records present in dataframe to S3.

Is there any way where I can parse the records and convert json to dataframe and write to s3?

or any other solutions provided will be helpfull

I have tried to use foreach but could not convert to dataframe to write to s3

```
def foreach_function(self,row):
   print("*"*100)
   print(row[0])
        
query = df.writeStream.foreach(self.foreach_function).start()
query.awaitTermination()
```

Answer (score 0):

Unclear why you need Spark for this.

Kafka Connect is part of Kafka, so only need to configure it to use [S3 Kafka Connect sink](https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connectors/s3-sink/current/overview.html) (which is open source), and it supports writing JSON files.

Comment: I need  to do some transformations like flatten json upon this

Comment: You did ask for alternatives. Ksql can do both https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/0.28.3-ksqldb/how-to-guides/use-connector-management/